# Migrate Software Deployed on Linux VM?

Tags: linux, deployment, clone, virtual-machine

I've got some software I created deployed on a Linux VM.  I'd like to deploy a second copy of the software on a second virtual machine.  Ideally, I'd like to just clone the VM volume, fire up a second copy, change the IP address, and that's that.  It there anything else to it, or is it really just that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname within the Linux VM has to be changed.  That's the only thing internal to the VM that must be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds fine to me, as long as your VM software is smart enough to change the VM's MAC address (VMware is at least)

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before in VMWare Workstation and Player - the VMX file has a MAC address which you can just change and VMWare will complain that the VM has moved (between physical machines only, I think) but you just tell it to create a new one when it starts and all will be fine.

Of course, you may have applications that don't like you doing that (license compliance managers or anything that stores the MAC or IP address between program runs and checks to ensure it hasn't changed).

In addition, I store all my VMs in their own directories so there's no conflict. Otherwise you'll have to rename files and change references to those files within the VMX and other configs.

I think you'll just have to suck it and see.